# iOS 7 - UISegmentedControl not staying highlighted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl that is being displayed within my UINavigationBar on an iPhone app running iOS 7.  I've noticed that when I select one of the values in the UISegmentedControl the highlighting does not stay active.  That is, if I select the first item, it triggers the action that I have added to it, but immediately un-highlights the value I selected.

Is this expected behavior?  A bug?  I don't recall ever seeing this in other apps using this control, and it works just fine on iOS 6.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you double-checked that the `momentary` property of the UISegmentedControl is `NO`? [(Apple docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/momentary).

Comment: D'oh!  That was it.  It was set to YES.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Should've had more faith in myself ;) have reposted as an answer now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the `momentary` property of the UISegmentedControl is NO ([Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/momentary)).