# How do I initialize a segmented control with a value from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol

My `UISegmentedControl` will not stay selected. I have made sure that [momentary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793576/ios-7-uisegmentedcontrol-not-staying-highlighted) is NO. So the solutions I have come across on here have not helped.

Would someone please be able to point me in the right direction?

EDIT

Thought I might make this question a bit clearer.

I have a `UISegmentedControl` and it has four selections (10,20,30,40) which changes the amount of questions asked on my quiz page. Making a selection works fine and changes the amount of questions.

But when I leave that view and go back later on to change the amount of questions again, it shows the selected as 10 even if I have selected something else.

How can I keep it showing the actual selected value?

EDIT

The number of questions is saved in NSUserDefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:amountOfQuestions forKey:@"Amount"]
```

How do I initialize a segmented control with a value from NSUserDefaults?

EDIT - Solved

```
#SettingsViewController .m file.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
amountOfQuestions = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Amount"];
if (amountOfQuestions == 10) {
mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}
```

I did not have the below code in my `IBAction` for my segmented control. So when i tried the above code it did not work. Now it works a treat.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Comment: How exactly do you "leave that view" and how do you "go back later"?  Show that code.

Comment: I have my ViewController (which is embedded in a navigation controller) then a button which pushes (no code just setup via storyboard) to my settingsPageViewController where my UISegmentedControl is. Not sure if this will help you at all.

Comment: When the "number of questions" selection is made, how is that selection saved?  How is that selection communicated to the quiz page?  It sounds like the settingsPageViewController is being re-instantiated every time it's shown so it starts with default values.  If you need the setting to be restored even if the app is terminated and re-started, a simple way is to save in NSUserDefaults.  There are plenty of examples of that.

Comment: The number of questions is saved in NSUserDefaults

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:amountOfQuestions forKey:@"Amount"];

Comment: Does the settingsPageViewController read that setting to initialize the value of the segmented control?

Comment: No, how do i do that? Sorry very new to this.

Comment: That's your "real" question that can be reasonably answered.  Edit your Question and add the info from the comments and include the new question "How do I initialize a segmented control with a value from NSUserDefaults?".

Comment: You need to show your code. There are many possibilities and it's impossible for anyone to diagnose your problem if you don't show us what you did. Note you have to include [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; to save any changes to user defaults.

Comment: That was my problem, i did not include [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]; Adding that line has solved the problem. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#SettingsViewController .m file.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
amountOfQuestions = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Amount"];
if (amountOfQuestions == 10) {
mySegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}
```

I did not have the below code in my IBAction for my segmented control. So when i tried the above code it did not work. Now it works a treat.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```